# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-J’

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++, worhp

I am getting this error after executing the corresponding Makefile of the [worhp](https://worhp.de/) optimization library:

```
[root@slave1 worhp]# make
gcc -O -Iinclude -Ifinclude/worhp -Jobj obj/c-example.o -Llib -lworhp -o 
bin/c-example -Wl,-rpath=../lib
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-J’
make: *** [c-example] Error 1
```

Taking a look at the Makefile, that option seems to be a gfortran option:

```
# Fortran compiler and flags
FC       := gfortran
FFLAGS   := $(FLAGS) -Ifinclude/worhp -Jobj
```

I am using gcc 4.9.2 and gfortran 4.8.5-11

Comment: You haven't shown us any rules for your makefile so we can't help.  I'm assuming that in your makefile there is an implicit or explicit rule specifying how to build the `bin/c-example` program, and in that rule's recipe the `FFLAGS` variable is being used for flags while the `CC` variable is being used for the command.  It's not clear from your question whether or not this program is supposed to be a FORTRAN program (in which case you should use `FC` as the program) or a C program (in which case you should use `CFLAGS` for the flags).

Answer (score 1):

At the end, what happened to me is that I had previously updated gcc in my machine but not gfortran. So I reinstalled gcc making sure that I added this to the configure step:

```
--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran
```

Now both gcc and gfortran have the same version and this error is not produced anymore.

Comment: Is there any other solution not involving a gcc rebuild ?